# Java - Mapping between custom interface and standard interface

Tags: java, junit

I have to manage a Java project that contains components defined through custom interfaces (e.g. IRunnable, IQueue, etc.) that do not extend the standard JDK version (e.g. Runnable, Queue, etc.) but are very similar. Does anyone know if and eventually how it is possible to map/replace custom interfaces to standard ones, for example inside jUnit test classes or in a sort of "configuration file/class" without modifying custom interfaces (i.e. to extend default ones)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**: added sample code

```
/* Custom interface */
public interface IRunnable {
    public void run()
}
```

...then in test code I need to "replace" a IRunnable type object with a Runnable type, in order to be able to write (for example):

```
IRunnable task;
(...some code to populate task...)
ScheduledFuture schedFut = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

...where the argument `task` should be a `Runnable` (and not a `IRunnable`) in order to perform the scheduling.

**EDIT 2**: added further clarifications

Suppose I have to write a jUnit test for `MyAbstractClass` (or any related non-abstract extensions).

```
public abstract MyAbstractClass {
    protected IRunnExec executor;
    public abstract IRunnable job();
    public final void execute() {
        executor.schedule(job());
    }
}

/* Custom interface */
public interface IRunnExec<Results> {
    public Results schedule(IRunnable task)
}
```

What is the best approach in order to keep original interfaces (e.g. `IRunnable`, `IRunnExec`) as they are and use the standard (provided by JDK) interfaces/class (e.g. `Runnable`, `ScheduledExecutorService`)?
I need to create an "Adapter" for every custom interface?

Comment: Without some detailed, concrete example code this is too abstract to have an answer.  Please show example code with complete definition of one of these not-quite-JDK interfaces, how it's being used and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Why negative votes?

Comment: I suspect because there's not enough information here to understand what you really want to accomplish.  The example you provided can't be made to work that way.  Adapting one interface to another would require a detailed understanding of both interfaces' contracts, which we don't have.  This may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 1):

If you can get rid of them, do so asJTeam says.

If you can't, create adapter between custom interface and standard one.

eg.

```
public class IRunnableRunnableAdapter implemets Runnable {
    private IRunnable iRunnable;
    public IRunnableRunnableAdapter (IRunnable iRunnable) {
        this.iRunnable = iRunnable;
    }

    public void run() {
        iRunnable.run();
    }
}
```

You could also tackle it at cunsuming side by creating class that mimicks consumers (eg Executors) but accepts custom interfaces too, applies adapter on them and then pass them to standard executor.